# I am getting error ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found while Performing Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, importerror, glibc, google-assistant

I am getting error
**ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)**

while Performing Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi

I am follwing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IW4Ssu-0-Er0ojO_1fIDjIfTK-RpHqXK/view?usp=sharing
this tutorial works fine on raspberry pi buster
but now on Raspberry Pi Legacy OS , its not working...

**My python --version is 3.7.3**
please check attached screenshot and plz help [image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the toolchain of the buster has GLIBC_2.29 version whereas Legacy OS might be built with an older toolchain version.
You might need to point your build to GLIBC_2.29 version.

Comment: I  get same error on raspberry pi bullseye os .Can you please help what to do next ? ho wto build GLIBS_2.29 version

Comment: 1. Can you please report the glibc versions that are available on the OS versions where you are seeing the issue?

ldd --version should do the trick.

2. If not 2.29, get the version of glibc from [here](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline)

3.  Install the newer version of glibc, but this can lead to a slew of problems and is not meant for begineers.

4. Instead, check if you can fall back to a different version of cpython, or use ubuntu on PI. Raspi typically doesn't have the latest version of glibc.

Comment: thanks for reply...
ldd --version gives version as 2.28on my system

so now what should i do ?
how to install glibc version 2.29 using link provided by you?

Comment: wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.29.tar.gz

tar -zxvf glibc-2.29.tar.gz

cd glibc-2.29

./configure --prefix=/opt/glibc

make 

make install

i tried to install glibc 2.29 using above commands ,but on last step (make install) gives error Makeconfig:42: *** missing separator. Stop.

please help

Comment: It's not possible for me to debug out the error by just looking at this minimal log and no access to the platform.